# Mongo Sharred Key definition and used in GO lang

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a program where I need to access Mongo Sharred Key from DB collection in Go lang. I retrieve the collection output as

```
map[string]interface{}
```

and type cast Mongo Sharred Key. However sometime its definition is int64 and sometime it is only int. So my Go program is getting panic sating

> "invalid interface conversion - interface is defined as int but its type is int64".

And when I change its definition to int64 again I am getting same type error for other records. Please help.

Comment: Could you post an example of a document that generates this error? It would probably be simpler if you defined your collection schema as a struct.

Comment: Thanks @user114241 ... the problem is that collection is schemaless.

Comment: Thanks @user114241-- I fixed the issue using "reflect".